# How to calculate Lucas Numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am a starting programmer and need to program an application in java which ask for a number and then prints the first n number of Lucas Numbers. for example when 7 is put in, it outputs: 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18.

Just to be clear, lucas numbers are defined as:

2  if n = 0

1 if n = 1

L(n-1) + L(n-2) if n>1

I am really not sure howver how to programm this in java. Because I cannot translate this into java code. I've been thinking for a while now but still can't figure it out. Also when i would have the code for calculating the Nth lucas number, i would now how to output all the first Lucan Numbers up until the Nth number. Can some of you guys help me gte on the right way or give me tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: is this homework? if so please tag it as such

Answer (score 5):

The definition you have for the Lucas number is recursive, i.e., to calculate the Nth lucas number, you already need to know the N-1th and the N-2nd.

A **naive** way to do this would be

```
public int lucas(int N) {
    if( N == 0 ) return 2;
    if( N == 1 ) return 1;
    return lucas(N-1) + lucas(N-2);
}
```

However, you only have to print the numbers, don't you? Then it's quite easy, actually.

```
int L2 = 2;
int L1 = 1;
for( int i = 2; i <= N; i++ ) {
    int L = L1 + L2;
    print(L); //or whatever output function you have
    L2 = L1;
    L1 = L;
 }
```

The idea is to keep the last two numbers, which you need to compute the next two numbers, always at hand.

PS: These Lucas numbers are just like the Fibonacci numbers with different starting values, so any algorithm for the Fibonacci numbers will do. If you're really good at math, you can even try to find a closed formula for the Lucas numbers, but it's definitely beyond high school math (search tag would be "linear difference equation with constant coefficients").

Comment: thanks for you answer. I used the first calculation you gave and got it to work so that when a number is put it i will get that nth Lucas Number to print out. However, i need to print out all the numbers up until the Nth Lucas Number to print out. How can i do this?

Comment: The thing is I don't nee to only print the numbers, but also a string in front of it like: The first N Lucas Numbers are: 2, 1, 3, 5, 7 for example. I understand the second piece fo code you wrote will print all the numbers, but how can I get these after the string "The first N Lucas Numbers are:". Because now i calculate in a seperate public static int Method instead of void. Does this make sense?

Comment: Look, in my second piece of code the comment says "...or whatever output function you have". What I've explained is how to compute all those numbers, so all you have to do is print them in a way that you're happy about. Also, this questions sounds a lot like homework/assignment, so you should try to figure things out for yourself, this will help you a great deal with future tasks, trust me.

Comment: Yes it is homework indead, just really didn't understand it anymore. Just started programming and it is a lot to comprehend all in once. For example, my previous question could be easily fixed when using system.out.print instead of the sytem.out.println which is was using all the time. I think I solved it right now. Much thanks for all your help with it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure how to do the whole thing, break the problem down into smaller pieces until you can start.

Try taking each case, one at a time. Implement the '2 if n=0' case, test that it works. The calculation is trivial, but you will have to write the code that calls your implementation, too. The trivial case helps you check that the code around it works properly.

Then implement the next one, check it still works, implement the final one. It'll become clearer as you go.

Comment: Your answer supports my impression that TDD cannot be used for anything else except implementing fibonacci.

Comment: Erm - TDD would involve writing the tests first. I've just described decomposition and testing. As the asker was clearly doing homework, I wasn't just going to write the code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking for a formula and happens on this page then maybe this will help.  In Windows take the following line and replace each `N` with the desired integer, copy the modified line and paste it into Windows' calculator:

> (5@/2+0.5)yN+(-(5@/2+0.5))y(-N)=

For example if you want to find the Lucus number for `7` you would paste this line into Windows' calculator:

> (5@/2+0.5)y7+(-(5@/2+0.5))y(-7)=

And the result will be `29`.